# Using DE-9IM patterns in python plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, de-9im

I'd like to compare geometries using DE-9IM patterns in my QGIS plugin written in Python. I've tried to instantiate QgsGeos but it seems there's no such module in qgis.core, as reported by the following Python exception :

```
> from qgis.core import QgsGeos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name QgsGeos
```

I could also use shapely but I don't know if this module is included in all QGIS distributions.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just found what I think is the good way to instantiate a QgsGeometryEngine (QgsGeos is a subclass of QgsGeometryEngine) :

```
my_geometry_engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(a_geometry)
```

(see https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a9d16b0eca18cf3a965d1a27e0b680004)

Comment: How would you run this on a layer to check if each polygon in the layer is contained within another polygon in the same layer?

Answer (score 3):

There's now a function called **relate** implemented in the expression editor which gives the DE-9IM matrix... just stumbled across it recently. I suspect it's fairly new, maybe new to 2.16?

[image: QGIS relate function]

You might want to look at the [QgsExpression class](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsExpression.html) - not tried this myself but it looks like that might be a way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen this but I have not yet found how to process geometries with QgsExpression.

Comment: I've just read the QgsExpression documentation. It would be a great solution if I wanted to evaluate expressions against features. In my case, I only have geometries (at this step of my process). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Python console of QGIS 2.18.13. A bit hacky though.

```
a = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('LINESTRING(40 40,120 120)')
b = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('LINESTRING(40 40,60 120)')

assert(isinstance(a, QgsGeometry))
assert(isinstance(b, QgsGeometry))

expr = QgsExpression("relate( geom_from_wkt( '{0}' ), geom_from_wkt( '{1}' ) )".format(a.exportToWkt(), b.exportToWkt()))
print(expr.expression())
print(expr.evaluate())
```

Outputs:

```
u"relate( geom_from_wkt( 'LineString (40 40, 120 120)' ), geom_from_wkt( 'LineString (40 40, 60 120)' ) )"
u'FF1F00102'
```

See also:

- http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Relate.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM